# How to read Windows environment variable value?

Tags: python, environment-variables

I tried this:

```
os.environ['MyVar']
```

But it did not work!
Is there any way suitable for all operating systems?

Comment: I got this error: 
KeyError: 'MyVar'

Comment: Are you sure that you defined variable in a right way?

Comment: How to define it? I have add it in Control Panel->System and Security -> System -> Advamced system settings->Environmental Variables

Comment: You can check the variable in the console using the command SET.

Comment: Did you set the environment variable after starting the shell you're running Python from?

Answer (score 64):

Try using the following:

```
os.getenv('MyVar')
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getenv):

> os.getenv(varname[, value])
>
> Return the value of the environment variable varname if it exists, or value if it doesn’t. value defaults to None.
>
> Availability: most flavors of Unix, Windows

So after testing it:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['MyVar'] = 'Hello World!'       # set the environment variable 'MyVar' to contain 'Hello World!'
>>> print os.getenv('MyVar')
Hello World!
>>> print os.getenv('not_existing_variable')
None
>>> print os.getenv('not_existing_variable', 'that variable does not exist')
that variable does not exist
>>> print os.environ['MyVar']
Hello World!
>>> print os.environ['not_existing_variable']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/UserDict.py", line 17, in __getitem__
    def __getitem__(self, key): return self.data[key]
KeyError: 'not_existing_variable
```

Your method would work too if the environmental variable exists. The difference with using `os.getenv` is that it returns `None` (or the given value), while `os.environ['MyValue']` gives a KeyError exception when the variable does not exist.

Comment: Whatever the combination is, by default it is printing out None.

Answer (score 27):

You might have to restart windows to be able to read the environment variable that you set through the control panel.

Comment: Or just restarting the console.

Comment: This worked! I tried just restarting Spyder and Jupyter Notebook, and neither could find the environment variables I needed. Once I restarted my computer, the os.getenv(wanted_env_var) function worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Had to restart machine, restarting console didn't cut it +1

Comment: What is console?

Comment: @BetterCallMe In this context, it could be a command prompt, PowerShell, Terminal, or any development environment being used. Usually, you will need to restart these for changes made to the System Environment Variables to reflect.

Answer (score 6):

```
os.getenv('PATH')
```

You can test it with the above line of code. It will list all the paths which are set.