# Can you set or delete an environment variable in python globally in windows?

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, environment

I need to have an option to add and remove global environment variables on runtime from my python code, is it possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496748/how-to-read-windows-environment-variable-value-in-python

Comment: You can, but they will only affect your process and subprocesses, and not other processes running on that same OS

Comment: Windows has a command-line `setx` command that "Creates or modifies environment variables in the user or system environment." You can execute it with the `os.system()` function.

Comment: @YvesDaoust that's about reading a variable, I need to set or delete one.

Comment: @MenyIssakov I need to set it for current and future runs of the *same program*, so I guess it's my answer?

Comment: Then you can set it in the very first beginning of your program (top of the main file your execute):


import os\n
os.environ['ENV_VARIABLE_NAME'] = 'VALUE'

Comment: @Tomergt45: are you unable to click on a link ?

Comment: @martineau, but if using setx.exe to modify `PATH`, do not modify that value of `os.environ['PATH']`. Use winreg to get the raw system or user value from the registry, either from "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" or, for the user value, "HKCU\Environment". The benefit of using setx.exe to write the modified value, as compared to just using winreg to write it, is that setx.exe broadcasts the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` "Environment" message that tells Explorer to reload its environment from the registry. You can do that directly in Python, but it requires ctypes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it in the very first beginning of your program (top of the main file your execute):

```
import os
os.environ['ENV_VARIABLE_NAME'] = 'VALUE'
```

but a better practice would be setting it outside of your application, e.g. if you have something running your app, then first use it to set the env variables, and then run your app.

even if it's shell:
export VAR=VALUE;python myapp.py...

Comment: If I would to use `os.environ['name'] = ...`, close my program completely and then run it again but instead of setting a variable, I execute `os.environ['name']` would it retrieve my variable?

Comment: No, this env variable you're setting as part of your program, is only available to your program, and any subprocesses you are spawning while the program is running

You can't set a global env variable from a running python process (at least I don't know of a way doing it from builtin Python modules).

think of it, would you want programs going around setting env variables that may affect other non related programs?

Even in your shell, your env variables are being set every time you open a new shell, they don't exist, your shell sets them every time you open it

Comment: so this is the closest option you can achieve in python, got it, thank you.

Comment: @Tomergt45, no this is not the closest you can get to your objective with Python. You can modify the value in the registry via winreg and broadcast the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` "Environment" message using ctypes. But one thing you will not be able to do is exit back to a command-line shell such as CMD, PowerShell, or bash and see the updated environment. Typically only Explorer updates its environment in response to an "Environment" message sent to its top-level windows, so the command-line shell needs to be restarted from Explorer.